# How to collect data from all components in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Angular components are mostly self-contained and do not pollute the global scope. However, I would like to collect all data of an application and save it.

Is there a common approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this approach now:

- parent component holds references to models of child components
- each child components is passed its model as parameter/binding
- the child component has to distinct between domain model and its own state attributes

This technique introduces some overhead, but it seems to work well. The dictinction between domain model and other attributes the components might want to use allows for a nice separation of concerns.

In code this looks something like this:

```
// parent template

<div class="message-list">
    <message ng-repeat="message in $ctrl.messages" model="message"
             on-delete="$ctrl.removeMessage(message)">
    </message>
</div>
```

---

```
// parent component

.component('messagelist', {
    templateUrl: 'core/messagelist/messagelist.html',
    controller: MessageListCtrl
});

function MessageListCtrl() {
    var message1 = {
        text: "message numero uno"
    };
    var message2 = {
        text: "message numero dos"
    };
    this.messages = [message1, message2];

    // (...)
}
```

---

```
// child template

<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.model.id" />
<textarea ng-model="$ctrl.model.text"></textarea>
```

---

```
// child component

.component('message', {
    templateUrl: 'core/message/message.html',
    controller: MessageCtrl,
    bindings: {
        model: "=",
        onDelete: "&"
    }
})

function defaultValue(current, defaultVal) {
    return typeof current !== "undefined" ? current : defaultVal;
}

function MessageCtrl() {
    this.$onInit = function () {
        this.model.id = defaultValue(this.model.id, "");
        this.model.text = defaultValue(this.model.text, "");
    }
}
```